# Add caption for diagram in tikz cd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[14pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\uMor}[1]{\operatorname{\underline{Mor_{#1}}}}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
(\mathcal{C}/U)^{\text{op}} \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{F}}(x,y)}"{name=U}, bend left=49] \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{G}}(\Psi(x),\Psi(y))}"'{name=D}, bend right=49] &  &  & (\text{Set})
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I want to add caption for a diagram in tikzcd code.

I want to name the figure say “Figure 1”

What are some ways to do that?

Comment: Why not put it into a `figure` environment and use the usual `\caption` approach. An alternative would be using the `\captionof{figure}{...}` command from the `capt-of` package.

Comment: I am not really very comfortable with this kind of things. Can you write in detail in an answer. @leandriis thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\uMor}[1]{\operatorname{\underline{Mor_{#1}}}}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzcd}
(\mathcal{C}/U)^{\text{op}} \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{F}}(x,y)}"{name=U}, bend left=49] \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{G}}(\Psi(x),\Psi(y))}"'{name=D}, bend right=49] &  &  & (\text{Set})
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{my caption text}
\end{figure}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
(\mathcal{C}/U)^{\text{op}} \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{F}}(x,y)}"{name=U}, bend left=49] \arrow[rrr, "{\uMor{\mathcal{G}}(\Psi(x),\Psi(y))}"'{name=D}, bend right=49] &  &  & (\text{Set})
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\captionof{figure}{my caption text}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Unrelated to the question, but you might want to keep in mind that the `hyperref` package should generally (with some few exceptions)  be the last package that you load.

Comment: Does the samething works if I want to write as equation? \begin{equation} \begin{tikzcd}\end{tikzcd}\end{equation}??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Yes, it does. Did you try this yourself?

Comment: It did not work... :O That is why I asked... It did not work for me atleast...

Comment: If I use the preamble from your question and insert the `tikzcd` environment  into an `equation` environment, I get the following result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcHoF.png

Comment: Yes, that I also got.. I want the diagram look like the one above with a caption and also equation number as 1 ...

Comment: Just to be sure I understand you correctly, is the following the output you wanto to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/noFPy.png

Comment: Yes Yes.. Exactly :) :) Sorry, what I am asking now is not my original question.. my original question is answered perfectly... Just got more curious and asked second question....

Comment: The image from my last comment was created using the `eqn` float type described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840493. However, this method will interfere with the standard equation numbering scheme. And you might also want to keep in mind, that the [`amsart` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) clearly states 'Please note that the use of any other numbering style will be changed to accord with standard AMS practice, which may run the risk of introducing inadvertent errors.' [See section5.7, page 15]